# Как в конфигурации 1С быстро найти элементы?

Tags: 1с

Для примера галочкой указал такие элементы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их быстро найти? Какие есть способы определить где они находятся?

Answer (score 0):

Заходишь в конфигуратор

1. в окне поиска, Панель "Конфигурация" набираешь текст
2. нажимаешь [Ctrl][Shift][F] Глобальный поиск и набираешь текст